# Why did I use ‘mov ah,9' twice，but the screen only print once?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGwHv.png)

**Why did I use ‘*mov ah,9*’ twice，but the screen only print once?**
I am a green hand about assembly,but I have some problem about it's grammer,in my book's programm,it is a cognizance process,when dw's value is less than zero,it will print 'dat is a negative number!',if more than zero, it will put 'dat is a nonegative number!', I also feel puzzled about 'jge isnn',why say that?

```
data SEGMENT 
    n db 'dat is a negative number!','$'
    nn db 'dat is a nonegative number!','$'
    dat dw -3
    
data ENDS
code SEGMENT
    assume cs:code,ds:data
start:
mov ax,data;data
mov ds,ax;ax
mov ax,dat;
cmp ax,0;cmp
jge isnn
lea dx,n;
mov ah,9;
int 21h
jmp finish
isnn:lea dx,nn;
mov ah,9;
int 21h
finish:
mov ah,4ch;
int 21h
code ENDS
end start
```

Comment: Single step in the debugger and observe the control flow.  Does it actually execute both the `int 21h`s?  There are also manuals that will explain what each instruction does.

Comment: you reminded me! This programm is a branch jump program,two 'int 21' is not execute both! This program in my teaching material is a part of branch jump program,.Because I have studied other Advanced computer languages before.I have a wrong thinking just like'if else', such as one if must have one else,thank you very much!